# Code Conversion from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, code-conversion

I really need help on converting this Objective-C Code to Swift, so that I can implement it into my code. Here's the code

```
NSLog(@"%@", [@"1 + 2" numberByEvaluatingString]);
```

I know that numberByEvaluatingString isn't an actual function in Objective-C, but in my code it will work.

Answer (score 2):

```
let string = "1 + 2"
let numberFromString = string.numberByEvaluatingString()
printLn("\(numberFromString)")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function to express a string as an arithmetic formula.

```
NSLog("%@",NSExpression(format:"1+2"))
```

You could also use println()

Edit: Also if you want the expression to be evaluated

```
let exp = NSExpression(format:"1+2")
println(exp.expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil))
```